# Condition Checking with Boolean

Tags: c#

I have a query in checking condition.

```
var hasListHeader = false;

using(SqlDataReader reader = sql.ExecuteQueryReturnDR(query, sqlParams)) //this will return SqlDataReader
{
   if(hasListHeader = reader.HasRows)
   {

   }
}
```

1. Can i check if condition like that? First assigning from `reader.HasRows` and then checking condition?

Instead of doing like this, am checking like above. Is that good practice?

```
hasListHeader = reader.HasRows;
if(hasListHeader)
{
}
```

Comment: I dont really understand your question. But I would use the first notation if I need the value of `hasListHeader` outside of the `using` block. If you dont need the value of `hasListHeader` outside of the `using` block then I would yust use `reader.HasRows` as the condition for the `if` but I think that is not the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
hasListHeader = reader.HasRows;
if(hasListHeader)
{
}
```

only if you intend to use the variable `hasListHeader` for later use, perhaps in the same method or elsewhere in the codebase.

If you don't need `hasListHeader` after the `if` statement, then I would remove it and use

```
if(reader.HasRows)
{
}
```

Comment: +1 the 'intent' is clear and simple in this solution, nice one!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can check boolean like that since assignment is an expression which has the value of the right-hand operand, so

```
hasListHeader = reader.HasRows
```

evalulates to the value of `reader.HasRows` and assigns that value to `hasListHeader` as a side-effect.

It's not considered good style to do this however, and moving the assignment above the `if` statement is considered clearer.